# Hidden rows in SSRS report while rendering in Excel format

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am encountering an very unusual behavior while rendering a SSRS report in EXCEL format. I have a simple SSRS report with one parameter (Country).It has only one tablix (table) with no report header and footer. This report will be generated by executing a SSIS package. The SSIS package will pass the country parameter (one parameter at a time) and invoke the data driven subscription associated with the report. Three reports will be generated in Excel format in the specific location provided for each parameter passed. Say, one report for parameter India, one for Pakistan and final one for Srilanka. After the report generation, Sometimes I find that the last row is hidden in any one or all of three reports generated. So, I converted the specification of table height & width, row height and column width from inches to pt as per the workaround suggested by Microsoft. But, it is behaving in unusual pattern after this modification too. Sometimes the report has no hidden last row and sometimes it has. Please note that every time, I have used the same sample data for this report generation.

Also, I have changed below properties of textboxes in tablix as per suggestion in one of the workaround post
Padding - 2pt,2pt,0pt,0pt
Vertical align - Middle
Can grow - false
an shrink - false

And tried increasing the row height from 15pt to 22pt. But above same unusual behavior persists. I have attached the screenshots of report design and sample report here Did anyone experienced this issue before. Any suggestions on this issue will be really helpful.

Report Design
[image: Report Design]

Here row 10045 is hidden
[image: Here row 10045 is hidden]

Answer (score 1):

After spending around an hour, I figured out the fix for it.

As mentioned by Microsoft the row height/width measurement has to be in points.
**The main part is you have to apply it for all the cells of the tablix.** Select `ALL` the cells and `Press F4` to get the properties window and do the required changes in points (shown below).

[image]

Note: The default height of excel row is 14.4pt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already applied this conversion from inches to pt for all the cells of tablix. But no luck. still the issue persists :(

Comment: Also, I have been using the same rdl for generating all the reports by passing different country parameters. I am not getting this hidden last row for all the reports generated.

Comment: Strange! Can you try textboxes padding with 0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt? What is the count of the rows where you have no issue?

Comment: Count of rows after which this hidden row exists is unpredictable too. For example, for country parameter India, report with 18555 records is generated with no hidden last row. But for Pakistan, report with 10043 records is generated with hidden last row. In another case, I could find hidden last row for 375 records itself. Really strange and inconsistent. Also, changing the padding of each textbox and tablix to 0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt didn't work too.

Comment: Last option, convert all the fields measurement to [pt] from [inch] (if left any). Open your report in XML mode (View code) and search for [in] and convert that to [pt].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All the field measurements are converted to pts. But still cant get rid off the hidden last row. I have implemented a workaround as of now (height - 36pt and cangrow - true). It works most of the times. But still few times, reports are generated with hidden last row. Not sure, what is the issue and what might be the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, what I did to fix:
1. Converted all the size from cms to pts, page size, report size, columns size, row size, tablix size.
2. It didnt work even after changing row height to 14.2pt, because font was verdana 10pt, and for that minimum 14.3pt is needed in excel
3. I have changed row height to 14.3 pt, and now it works always. No more hidden rows.

Hope this helps.